# EMM - MDM notification not being delivered on iOS devices

Tags: wso2-iot

I have setup WSo2 EMM correctly. Noticed that device information and Get All Applications Notifications go pending and are never delivered to the devices. The status of these notifications in the database table is also P. 
The only way to deliver these messages are by pushing the Camera Enable/Disable Operation or some other notifications, then the older pending notifications get delivered. 
Seems they are stuck. This also happens to policy enforcement notifications. I have to manually push camera disable/enable to make these works.
Why does this happen? The notifications should be delivered instantly, like they do in Camera Enable/Disable case.

I am connected in Production Mode. Any pointers to sort this out?

Comment: I also tried with another MDM APNS Certificate and with it everything was fine. Why with my MDM APNS Certificate it is like this? I can't say there is an issue with the certificate because the commands are delivered when I take a manual operation like disable camera etc. Please help, I am completely lost with this.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Java 1.6 earlier. Once I switched the JDK to 1.7, it appears to so far work well.